# Python Def Syntax Error with . in file name

Tags: python, visual-studio, fastq

In my Visual Code Studio running python3.6 - my code is saved as `"Langemead12Test.py" w/ lines` as:

> !C:\Users\Bones\Anaconda3\python.exe
>   [1]def readFastq(SRR835775_1.first1000.fastq)
>
> Red Error underline def [pylint] E0001:invalid syntax (, line 3).

In Anaconda command prompt running python3.6:

> File "Langmead12Test.py", line 3
>       def readFastq(SRR835775_1.first1000.fastq)
>                                ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Question(s): I'm a total newb here but I can't seem to understand why VCS throws an error under def and my anaconda command line prompt throws error at the . within the fastq filename. Are these independent errors or different representations of the same error? All thoughts and hints are welcome.

Background: I am attempting to execute exercise in ADS1: Practical: Working with sequencing reads. Ben Langmead's Youtube class on reading fastq files (`filename = SRR835775_1.first1000.fastq`).

Comment: You probably want quotes around `SRR835775_1.first1000.fastq`, and they're probably the same error.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the code? It looks like you are trying to define a function. The function's parameters are simple names, no dots. I can't say whether that's the only error without a view of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 syntax error in one line:

1.Missing "" or this '' before and after your string

2.You forget to put ":" and the end of the line: 
Correct syntax:

```
def readFastq(filename="SRR835775_1.first1000.fastq"):
```

Read this carefully please:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

And after that read and learn everything from there:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: if you still getting error pls post your code as asked before

Comment: Thank you for your reply; in the tutorial I was attempting to replicate the user is in Jupyter notebook and doesn't use quotes or : I gather this Jupyter has some way of departing form normal syntax?

Comment: Here is the new error from Anaconda Prompt File                    "Langmead12Test.py", line 3
    def readFastq('SRR835775_1.first1000.fastq'):
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: My bad i made a mistake edited the code in my answer test it now. because you still not posted the actual code which reads the file in your function i guessing the argument name is filename in your function :)  if not change it accordingly

Comment: I dont know I never used Jupyter nor Anaconda But thats what Jupyter.org says so it should work:"When executing code in IPython, all valid Python syntax works as-is" so try update the code from my edited answer and see if it works